# Edit datatip position in p:chart

Tags: charts, primefaces, tooltip, jqplot

I'm using PrimeFaces 6.0 and I want to show tooltip on my bar chart. I tried datatipeditor like [this example](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2044) and it worked fine. The problem is, I might use long text for the tooltip and the most left bar won't show the full text [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EGaC.png).

I tried to move the position with this code.

```
function toolTip(str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot){
     var val = plot.data[seriesIndex][pointIndex];
     return "<div style='position:relative; left:80px; bottom:15px;'>1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa: " + 
        (pointIndex +1) + "<br/>2bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb: " + val + "</div>";
}
```

The text moved as the i designed, but the box still there [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpXn9.png).

I was thinking to use extender, but i'm lost at the documentation page about which attribute to use and how to pass data from bean as tooltip's text.

Any idea how to move the both the box and text to the position I designed with datatipeditor?

Comment: This is more a hint than anything else that if you use Extender (which you can find examples of people using) the tooltips are set by the JqPlot Highlighter plugin which maybe the "sizeAdjust" property is what you want.  http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-highlighter-js.html#$.jqplot.Highlighter

Comment: i solved it with jqplot extender, thanks

Comment: Nice.  Can you please post your solution below as an "answer" and then mark it as the SOLVED answer. That is being a good Stack Overfow citizen for the next person!

Comment: I posted my solution but can't mark it as answer atm, it said i can accept it tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside bean:

```
CartesianChartModel barModel = new BarChartModel();
barModel.setExtender("myExtender");
```

Then in my js i use tooltipContentEditor from highlighter, here's the code:

```
function myExtender(){
     this.cfg.highlighter = {
          tooltipContentEditor: function (str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot) {
             var val = plot.data[seriesIndex][pointIndex];
             return "this value is: " + val + "<br/>this is a looooooooooooong text";
          },
     show: true, 
     useAxesFormatters: false,
     tooltipLocation: 'n'
     };
}
```

Here's the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UBHq.png).